# Display Range Axis Value as Alphabet using Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart, jfreechart

I had create new bar chart in which my y axis value are numeric but as per my requirement i need to change it with any kind of character. Is it possible to change value of y axis from numeric to Alphabet?

Comment: for more understanding of my question and see image about my problem http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/956781/display-range-axis-value-alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got my Solution.

Jasper Report is internally use JFreeChart for creating chart.
By Using JFreeChart, i was created chart Image those fulfill my requirement and i was added those image to my jrxml file.

Thanks for help

Comment: By using JFreeChart Library, Create an Image (outside jasper) that you required and add images in PDF.